# Flexslider not center li

Tags: javascript, html, flexslider

Flexslider has strage behaivor, when i load my web page without activing flexslider (but loading flexslider.css) you see something like this
[image]

Red border is the ul, black border is the li, li element is centered. but when i load flexslider. `$('.flexslider').flexslider();`on the console you get something like this
[image]

html

```
<div class="slider clearfix">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flexslider loading " style="text-align:center;">
                <ul  class="search-results slides" style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 25px; border-color:red; margin:0 auto;">
                    <li  class="search-entry container" style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 25px;">
                        <div>
                            <div class="contain">
                                <img src ="<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/images/slider-bg-1.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </li>
                    <li  class="search-entry container" style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 25px;">
                        <div>
                            <div class="contain">
                                <img src ="<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/images/slider-bg-2.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the css
[css file](http://pastebin.com/v10H5axK)

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What exactly would you like to do? Also, please post your code. Most likely the flexslider plugin has some overriding styles.

Comment: we need to see your styles and markup!